# Retain same session id as before

Tags: php, session

```
session_start();
```

I create an entry in the database and the user can edit it online..
Now, the user has closed the browser. And tomorrow he opens it and goes to the same site.
Is it possible to retain the same session id as before so that he can edit the same data, rather than having to goto the beginning ?

Comment: if you set the session expires time to infinite then its happen. Set the session expire in the server.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is often used, in this situation, is to :

- have a not too long session duration : it will expire if the user is
  not active (that's just the way it works -- and that's better for
  your server if you have lots of users)
- when user logs in, you set a cookie that contains what is needed for
  him to be recognized
- if he comes back on the site (with the cookie, and without having an
  active session), you use the informations contained in that cookie to
  auto-log him in, re-creating the session at the same time.

This way :

- you don't have thousands of sessions "active" with no good reason you
  keep the standard way sessions work
- And you have the advantage of "never being looged out", at least from
  the user's point of view.